# How to run spring boot docker image in my website directory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, containers

is it possible to run a spring boot docker image on my website folder I have created? An if yes how?

I access the server of my website via SSH. There I have created a folder, after my domain folder like:

- some/folders/my-webseite-domain/createdFolder

I have some APIs coded in Spring Boot and made an image out of it. The Request mappings are lets say "class/firstRequest" and "class/secondRequest".

How can I run these Docker images that the containers runs on path:

- https://my-website-domain.com/createdFolder/class/firstRequest

or

- https://my-website-domain.com/createdFolder/class/secondRequest

How do I do this?

Comment: I must say, that I do not understand what you are trying to do. Normally when you want to access files inside a docker container from the host system you mount volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

And the path of the orl is done via @RequestMappings in Spring and has nothing to do with directory structures

Comment: My purpose is to put my SprIng Apps into the secret folder I have created. So that I can only access that when I tipe that specific URL like: -www.mywebsite.com/secretFolder.

Comment: Then I would put a proxy like ngnix or an Apache in front of it. Or of you already into the spring Framework perhaps you can use spring Cloud Gateway (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/)